# Find $E[XY]$ given that $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y$ is a RV such that $E[Y|X=x] = ax+b$ and $Var [Y|X=x]=1.$

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and let $Y$ be a RV such that $E[Y|X=x] = ax+b$
>   and $Var [Y|X=x]=1.$
>   **Find $E[XY]$.**

I found $E[Y]$ using the law of total expectation, and I found $Var[Y]$ using the law of total variance.
Now I am not sure how to proceed since I do not know the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$.
I was thinking that maybe they were independent and then this becomes simple, however, I am not sure that that they are independent.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Y is a linear function of X, so it is very much not independent.  But there are formulas for this situation.  (Not that I remember them at the moment, but perhaps they're in whatever book you're using).

Comment: @nomen That is what I thought. I've gone through the book and can't find anything relevant to this scenario.

Comment: do you have any formulas to calculate the covariance between X and Y?  If so, look at the formula that defines C(X,Y) carefully and see what you can figure out based on the problem data.

Comment: @nomen The formulas I have for Covariance that would allow me to solve it require me knowing what the value of the Covariance is. Is this not the case with the formula you have?

Comment: That depends.  In this situation, (X,Y) are jointly normal, so there is a simple formula for the correlation and covariance.  But if your book didn't cover it, you'll have to prove the formula.

Comment: @nomen how do we know that the RVs are jointly normal?

Comment: Because Y is a linear function of X, so Y is normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103767/discussion-between-jac-frall-and-nomen).

Comment: $E[XY]=E[E[XY\mid X]]=E[XE[Y\mid X]]=\cdots$